# Display same scales on both y axes on a dual line chart

Tags: charts, tableau-api, linechart

I have a dual axis line chart that shows the number of *planned hours* vs *worked hours* through time (week number). Even though they are both Hours, I had to create a second axis for *worked* so that I get both of them displayed on the same chart.

But as you see in the picture, they do not quite show the correct scales (*Worked hours* is in thousands (0K, 2k, 4k, etc) while *planned hours* is in singles (0, 200, 400).
[image]

How can I edit my chart so they both show the same scale?

P.S. As long as I get both of these measures on the same chart, I really don't mind skipping the dual axis part. In fact, if both measures have the same scale I don't understand why one should create dual axis.

Comment: Hey. You should be able to just right click on the axis on the left and in the menu there shouldd be an option to "synchronize axis"

Comment: Why did you need dual axis for this particular application?  Would using [Measure Values] and filtering for those two measure not have worked?

Comment: @lampbob oh that was too hidden for me. please post it as answer if you want.

Comment: @tyvich but they are shown as two different charts that way. how can i have them both in the same chart?

Comment: @Diasterkid https://www.interworks.com/blog/jwright/2012/06/18/multi-measure-dual-axis-charts  Take a look at this link.  If you need to do more than just two measure values on the same chart you'll want to use the [Measure Values] pill vs. the dual axis.  Although for two measures dual axis can provide a bit more functionality.  Let me know if you can't get it to work

Comment: @Disasterkid Also This link: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46693583/how-to-combine-the-different-y-axes-into-one-y-axis-in-tableau/46696900?noredirect=1#comment80344201_46696900

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just right click on the axis on the left and in the menu there should be an option to "synchronize axis". Select this and it will sync the two axes.

You can then hide the axis on the right to make it appear like a regular line graph and not a dual axis. To do this right click on the axis and uncheck the "show header" option.