# How to combine the different y-axes into one y axis in Tableau

Tags: data-visualization, tableau-api, percentage

in Tableau I would like to figure out how to combine the y-axes for Former smoker, Never smoked, Smoke everyday, and Smoke some days. I want one y axis that ranges from 0.00 to 1. I appreciate any help, thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure your ideal graph output, but instead of plotting each individual measure.  Drag the [Measure Values] pill to the y axis and filter for the measures you want.  You can then drag [Measure Names] to the color shelf to make a line for each measure.

Comment: That's it. Thank you!